# Fill Sparse Data with SQL (Rockset)

Tags: sql, time-series, rockset

We have created the following query in order to convert sparse time series data into dense data with specific time slots. The idea is that a time range (e.g. 1 hour) is converted into distinct time slots (e.g. 60 x 1 min slots). For each slot (1 min in this example) we compute if there are one or more values and if there are we use a MAX function to get our value. If there are no values in the time range we use the one from the previous slot.

Here is the basic query:

```sql
WITH readings AS (
  (
    -- Get the first value before the time window to set the entry value
    SELECT
      timestamp AS timestamps,
      attributeId AS id,
      DATE_TRUNC('second', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp)) AS ts,
      value AS value
    FROM
      node_iot_attribute_values
    WHERE
      attributeId = 'cu937803-ne9de7df-nn7453b2-na2c7e14'
      AND DATE_TRUNC('second', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp)) < TIMESTAMP '2021-10-26T08:42:06.000000Z'
    ORDER BY
      ts DESC
    LIMIT
      1
  )
  UNION
    (
      -- Get the values in the time range
      SELECT
        timestamp AS timestamps,
        attributeId AS id,
        DATE_TRUNC('second', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp)) AS ts,
        value AS value
      FROM
        node_iot_attribute_values
      WHERE
        attributeId = 'cu937803-ne9de7df-nn7453b2-na2c7e14'
        AND DATE_TRUNC('second', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp)) > TIMESTAMP '2021-10-26T08:42:06.000000Z'
        AND DATE_TRUNC('second', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp)) < TIMESTAMP '2021-10-26T09:42:06.000000Z'
    )
),
slots AS (
  -- Create time slots at the correct resolution
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP '2021-10-26T08:42:06.000000Z' + MINUTES(u.i - 1) AS last_ts,
    TIMESTAMP '2021-10-26T08:42:06.000000Z' + MINUTES(u.i) AS ts
  FROM
    UNNEST(SEQUENCE(0, 60, 1) AS i) AS u
),
slot_values AS (
  -- Get the values for each time slot from the readings retrieved
  SELECT
    slots.ts,
    (
      SELECT
        r.value
      FROM
        readings r
      WHERE
        r.ts <= slots.ts
      ORDER BY
        r.ts DESC
      LIMIT
        1
    ) AS last_val,
    (
      SELECT
        MAX(r.value)
      FROM
        readings r
      WHERE
        r.ts <= slots.ts
        AND r.ts >= slots.last_ts
    ) AS slot_agg_val,
  FROM
    slots
)
SELECT
  -- Use either the MAX value if several are in the same slot or the last if none
  CAST(ts AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris' AS string) AS ts,
  COALESCE(
    slot_agg_val,
    LAG(slot_agg_val, 1) OVER(
      ORDER BY
        ts
    ),
    last_val
  ) AS value
FROM
  slot_values
ORDER BY
  ts;
```

The good news is that the query works. The bad news is the performance is terrible!!!

Interestingly the part of the query that retrieves the data from storage is very performant. In our case this part of the query returns all the results in ~50ms

```sql
WITH readings AS (
  (
    -- Get the first value before the time window to set the entry value
    SELECT
      timestamp AS timestamps,
      attributeId AS id,
      DATE_TRUNC('second', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp)) AS ts,
      value AS value
    FROM
      node_iot_attribute_values
    WHERE
      attributeId = 'cu937803-ne9de7df-nn7453b2-na2c7e14'
      AND DATE_TRUNC('second', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp)) < TIMESTAMP '2021-10-26T08:42:06.000000Z'
    ORDER BY
      ts DESC
    LIMIT
      1
  )
  UNION
    (
      -- Get the values in the time range
      SELECT
        timestamp AS timestamps,
        attributeId AS id,
        DATE_TRUNC('second', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp)) AS ts,
        value AS value
      FROM
        node_iot_attribute_values
      WHERE
        attributeId = 'cu937803-ne9de7df-nn7453b2-na2c7e14'
        AND DATE_TRUNC('second', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp)) > TIMESTAMP '2021-10-26T08:42:06.000000Z'
        AND DATE_TRUNC('second', TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp)) < TIMESTAMP '2021-10-26T09:42:06.000000Z'
    )
)
```

Having analysed the different parts of the query the one that is exploding the performance is this:

```sql
slot_values AS (
  -- Get the values for each time slot from the readings retrieved
  SELECT
    slots.ts,
    (
      SELECT
        r.value
      FROM
        readings r
      WHERE
        r.ts <= slots.ts
      ORDER BY
        r.ts DESC
      LIMIT
        1
    ) AS last_val,
    (
      SELECT
        MAX(r.value)
      FROM
        readings r
      WHERE
        r.ts <= slots.ts
        AND r.ts >= slots.last_ts
    ) AS slot_agg_val,
  FROM
    slots
)
```

For some reason this part takes ~25 seconds to execute! I would really appreciate some help in optimizing this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use JOIN and AGGREGATION logic to compute this. SQL works well with map and reduce logic.

Try

```
SELECT
    filled_slots.ts,
    MAX(value) AS last_val,
    slot_agg_val
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        slots.ts,
        MAX(previous_r.ts) last_previous_time,
        MAX(in_interval_r.value) AS slot_agg_val,
      FROM
        slots
        LEFT JOIN readings previous_r ON previous_r.ts <= slots.ts
        LEFT JOIN readings in_interval_r ON in_interval_r.ts < slots.ts
        AND in_interval_r.ts > slots.last_ts
      GROUP BY
        slots.ts
    ) filled_slots
    LEFT JOIN readings ON filled_slots.last_previous_time = readings.ts
  GROUP BY
    filled_slots.ts,
    slot_agg_val
```

The last one aggregation is useful to avoid issues due to duplicated data.
Code is not tested.

Comment: At < 600ms that is an epic improvement! Awesome suggestion... Unfortunately its not working quite as expected. For some reason there are a couple of values that are missing in the result set. The first couple of values returned by the old code are:

`ts,value
2021-10-26T10:42:06,-7.0
2021-10-26T10:43:06,-6.6
2021-10-26T10:44:06,-7.1`

And the new code:

`ts,value
2021-10-26T10:42:06,
2021-10-26T10:43:06,-6.6
2021-10-26T10:44:06,-7.1`

The initial -7.0 seems to be missing.

Comment: Having properly inspected the query the logic used to get the` last_val` doesn't work properly. Hence the missing values.

Comment: Oups, the left join should be on the last_previous_time ofc ...
`LEFT JOIN readings ON filled_slots.last_previous_time = readings.ts`

If it's working as expected, I edit my answer

Comment: Boom!!!! Amazing work (especially without access to the data)!